# Five element puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, language, anagram, chemistry

Born from water sun stone be B.
Five elements are ki.

The first give three, the rest he.
In five symbols, eight see.

From them form, evidently
That which is written for thee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This puzzle involves some wordplay based on...

> ...the **first five elements of the Periodic Table**: Hydrogen (H), Helium (He), Lithium (Li), Beryllium (Be), and Boron (B).

*Born from water sun stone be B.*
*Five elements are ki.*

> The first line here clues each of these five elements in order:
>
>  - 'Born from water' = Hydrogen, whose name means '*water*-forming'.
>  - 'Born from sun' = Helium, whose name is derived from 'helios', meaning *sun*.
>  - 'Born from stone' = Lithium, whose name is derived from 'lithos', which is Greek for *stone*.
>  - 'be' and 'B' simply clue the elemental symbol and starting letters of the next elements, **Be**ryllium and **B**oron.
>
>  As the five simplest elements in existence, these would have been the first to form during the creation of the Universe and are a vital part of existence itself, perhaps enabling us to draw comparisons with the life-force ('ki') of existence itself. ('Ki' is also a homophone of 'key', meaning 'important to this'...)

*The first give three, the rest he.*
*In five symbols, eight see.*

> Across all five elements their symbols have *eight* letters. The first two symbols together (H and He) have *three* letters. The remainder are referred to here as 'he' - the subject of the next section of the riddle...

*From them form, evidently*
*That which is written for thee.*

> Focussing on our 'he' subject requires us to use the symbols of the other three elements, Li, Be and B to identify 'him' - we can anagram these to *form* the word **BIBLE**, a book that *is written for thee* in a couple of senses: God's message to you (as Christians would esteem it), and an emphasis on the old English used in the King James Version ('thee' for 'you').

Comment: rot13(Gurer'f fbzr zber rknpg jbeqcynl naq purzvfgel va yvar guerr.)